# Dynamic row display in ie11

Tags: html, css

We are starting support for IE11 for our application. Considering this our application should work fine in both IE11 and IE8. Having problem specifically with the dynamic row display. attaching the HTML code below. If you notice the width of custom row doesn't respond correctly. 
Any suggestions are most welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd XHTML 1.0   transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/Dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<style>
 #customwidth{
 background-color: #ffffe1;
 width: 62%;
 }
</style>
<body>
<table width="746px" cellspacing="0" id="productTable">
<tr id="productid">
<td width="165px" <label for="Product">Product</label></td>
<td width="200px">

     <select id="prodSel" onchange='changeit()'>
      <option value="one" >Select Product</option>
      <option value="two">Product 1</option>
      <option value="three">Product 2 </option>

     </select>
     </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="165px">Term</td>
 <td width="200px"><select>
    <option >5 years</option>
    <option >10 years</option>
    <option >15 years</option></td>
</tr>
<tr id="amountid"  style="display: none">
<td id="customwidth">Amount</td>
<td width="200px"><input type="text"></td>
<td >
</tr>
<script>
document.getElementById("prodSel").change = function() {changeit()};
function changeit(){
  var x= document.getElementById('prodSel').value;
  if (x == 'three')
  {
     document.getElementById('amountid').style.display = 'block';
  }
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing table row element, you need to set a `display` property to `table-row`, not `block`:

```
document.getElementById('amountid').style.display = 'table-row';
```

Also validate your HTML, you have many problems like unclosed tags, invalid attributes (width="746px"),  etc. It can lead to broken rendering especially in IE.

Comment: Thanks ya. That works at one time but not the other. Not able to understand why it is showing different behavior.